# magento 2 checkout page shipping address validation not working after applying advanced js bundling

Tags: magento2.3, validation, advanced-bundling

I have applied advanced js bundling. Everything works fine except shipping address validation on the checkout page. 
After applying bundling checkout page shipping address validation is not working for new customers (mean if an address is not added before and someone fills shipping address on checkout page). Like it shows errors if the phone is empty but it also proceeds to the next step

[image]

It is showing phone number is a required field but at the same time it goes to the next page.

Update:
After further investigation i found that in `abstract.js this.source()` is null thats why it is not going inside if condition.
[image]

without advanced js bundling this.source is not null and it runs this statement `this.source.set('params.invalid', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this patch:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/files/4060889/fix-checkout-form-validation.txt

To read how to apply patches with composer, continue here: https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-javascript-bundling-setup-default/

Also, can you share what version of Magento you are on?

Comment: hi, thanks alot for your reply. i really appreciate it. I am using magento 2.3.2 version. i will apply patch and let you know.

Comment: @wilem wigman it works. Thanks alot